# How to determine how MyEclipse deploys Tomcat webapp

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, intellij-idea, war, myeclipse

I was given a MyEclipse project that deploys an app to Tomcat. The deployment works fine and I can run the app in the MyEclipse IDE.

I prefer to use IntelliJ for development. IntelliJ has the artifact and facet properties screen where I could determine exactly where in the webapp directory classes, resources, and libraries are deployed. Is there a place where I can find out in MyEclipse where it's copying all the parts of the webapp, so I can recreate this project in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Servers view, double click the tomcat server -- this screen has the information you are looking for. If the Servers window isn't currently displayed, select Window / Show View / Servers.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not looking for WHERE the WAR it gets deployed. I'm looking for HOW the stuff inside the WAR gets deployed. For example, directory xyz gets copied to WEB-INF/classes or resources directory abc gets copied to the WAR root.  The Servers view only has the mode and whole WAR location. (sorry for the multiple edits)

Comment: Try right-clicking the project in the Project Explorer, then selecting Properties, and then choosing Deployment Assembly.

Comment: When I do that, the form says "The given project is not a virtual component project". However, I did test that with a new from-scratch webapp, and that appears to be the screen I need. You get the check.

Comment: Thanks. I looked up the error you mention and found this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349039 (you get the error if you delete a component described by the Deployment Assembly), but it looks like that may be fixed if you upgrade your eclipse.